# Advanced lighting in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm learning WebGL and found a couple of useful tutorials around the web, that helped me to acquire some basic knowledge on this topic, but they all seem to stop at the point, when things are getting really interesting, especially in terms of lighting!

Until now, I understand how to implement some basic local lighting using the Phong reflection model, including ambient, diffuse and specular lighting, alternatively using directional or point lighting, per vertex or per fragment lighting.

So, that for sure is a good thing to start with, but of cause this kind of method is very much limited and regarding the fact, that the quality of lighting is crutial to the realism of a scene, I really want to go a step further.

But that's way easier said than done! I've been looking for tutorials or articles, describing how to implement more sophisticated methods of lighting into WebGL, but I couldn't find *anything* helpful yet!

It's like standing in front of a thick wall without a door and with no way around! - Simply frustrating.

Now, because I couldn't find WebGL related information about the implementation of global illumination models or descriptions of how to use things like ray tracing and all the other stuff, developped to make scenes look more realistic, I tried to do some reverse engineering on a couple of these really amazing WebGL works one can easily find.

But due to the complexity of the matter and because of the lack of insightful comments or even halfway expressive names for variables or functions, and, of cause, the limits of my own skills, I failed miserably!

I then tried to pursue a more theoretical attempt, reading papers about the mathematical basics, but it turned out, that it's a *really* long way from - in most cases poorly explained - mathematical formulas in no programming context, to a working implementation in my WebGL code, so, doing it this way was just as ineffective as my previous efforts...

Well, I know, asking for helpful ressources concerning this topic would be considered inappropriate on this board (though I have no clue, where I could ask for this otherwise) and my posting would likely to be closed, so I'm going to add a more specific question to it:

When illuminating an object using a local lighting model like, for example, the Phong reflection model, I create the geometry in JavaScript and pass it to the vertexshader together with the precalculated normals, then I multiply the values of the position and the normal data with the related matrices and pass the results to the fragmentshader, where the color of each pixel is calculated using the algorithms provided by the lighting model.

But in case I want to implement a *global* lighting model, it cannot work this way, can it? I mean, this would require to have *all* the information about the geometry of the scene into *one* shader, so I would have to call `gl.drawArrays( )` or `gl.drawElements( )` just once and have *everything* I want to be affected by lighting into one buffer, do I?

That doesn't sound neither like a performant nor like a practical solution to me, so there surely is a better way to get this together, isn't it? Now, how do I solve the problem of geometry being defined independently in JavaScript, but global lighting being calculated based on the vertex data of the *whole* scene in GLSL?

I'd be thankful for any help! And lastly, please excuse my bad english.

**EDIT**

PS: Yes, I definitely would have liked to ask in a more specific way, but being specific actually *is* the main problem I face regarding this subject... ;-)

Nevertheless, concerning my question of how to calculate global lighting when the geometry of the scene is defined independently, I recognized, that in many shader sources I tried to analyze, the geometry seemed to be created entirely in the fragmentshader, with only a simple square passed in from JavaScript.

But having basically the whole scene, the whole program, defined in the fragmentshader, will only work for very few and simple geometric models, I would think. So, if I'd keep defining my geometry in JavaScript, what (realistic) options would I have to exchange Information between the shaders, so that I can implement some global illumination algorithms?

Comment: Check out http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/25/webgl-deferred-irradiance-volumes/ and http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/dec/09/minecraft-like-rendering-experiments-in-opengl-4/.

Comment: Thank you for the links, WaclawJasper! I have no clue what I'm talking about, but I kind of remember reading something about **deferred shading** having a big disadvantage as not being able to properly handle transparency, but I heavn't read the article yet, so maybe this is something different anyway... It could be useful!

Comment: Advanced lighting techniques you are after all pretty much require deferred shading/multi pass rendering. For example, the basic technique for creating shadows is to first write to a depth texture on first pass and then do another pass to render the scene. Transparency is a big pain in the ass in general and you are gonna run into lots of issues with it. For starters, proper alpha blending/transparency requires that you draw all the geometry from back to front in camera space. However, arbitrary sorts kills batching, sorting is expensive and proper sort may not be even possible.

Comment: An insightful look at how a number of approximation techniques are used to layer a complex visual look: http://www.adriancourreges.com/blog/2016/09/09/doom-2016-graphics-study/

Answer (score 2):

In real world, every single surface reflects part of the light that comes to it and it absorbs other part of it. There are few objects that actually emit light, and that is what punctual light are used for, to simulate those light-emitting objects (light bulbs == point light, directional == sun etc). Games approximate lighting effects by just using those punctual light sources to describe lighting and assuming that calculations are are only local for a certain light&mesh pair, meaning, one mesh only cares about the light sources in its proximity, and indeed is oblivious of the other objects in the scene. To account for such effects where one object actually affects the lighting on another object, rendering engines use techniques that create shadows or approximate color bleed (global illumination).

Path tracing gets it right: shadows, color bleed, lighting, caustics... those are not separate phenomena, they are all produced by photons bouncing around the scene and interacting with the materials. For example, ambient occlusion and shadows are the same effect: the more the shadows become soft and subtle, they become ambient occlusion. Color bleed is just an effect where so much light is reflected of the nearby surface that the surface reflecting the light can be kind of considered as the light source. So all effect are interchangeable, and are the result of light scattering.

Game engines can't afford to simulate all those behaviors on such large scale and in such detail, and that's why they split lighting into certain, very differentiated, effects. So they lit object locally, then calculate shadowing, then try to find color bleed... Then they calculate camera effects independently like bloom, motion blur... All those effects and passes are artificially split into different groups to be real-time and are split by the amount and the type of information that they carry.

All things done in real-time rendering are approximations that do things more locally because computers don't have enough compute power to simulate all the effects on the global scale. The way to trick those limitations is to precalculate things, or do them dynamically, but to be simple enough for them to be real time. For example, for color bleed, we can precompute the light transport throughout the scene and approximate it by using big number of point light that each corresponds for the lighting in that certain volume of the scene where the light is placed (this techniques is called virtual point light).

In order to do real-time global illumination effects, and considering the limitations of the GPU, you need to approximate things and simplify them. So you end up using VPL or voxel cone tracing or screen-space photon mapping, or prefiltered local cube-maps, or any other technique that may suit your needs. You represent the global data in the fashion that can still be accessed and used locally, that approximates the entire scene good enough. So each object won't ever know about the entirety of the scene (well, that's what pathtracing does) but it will be given with some data that represents global lighting locally.

I hope this makes sense and that it helps.

AFTER EDIT:

You can't exchange the data between the shaders. You can try and voxelize your scene, and then pass that 3D texture that you got to all of the shaders. So all shaders are still independent of each other, but they manage to calculate global effects by using same data that represent entirety of the world.

Comment: This really lights up things a bit! ;-) Especially the thing about turning the scene into a 3D texture seems like being an elegant way of sharing information. Anyway, theres a lot to think about for me! - Thank you very much Abstract Algorithm!

Comment: WebGL still doesn't support 3D textures. Something like combination of virtual point light and deferred rendering is probably the best choice currently. Prefiltered local cube-maps are also an option, and also spherical harmonics, but none of these is too dynamic. Upvote the answer if it helped.